# Выборка из двух таблиц mssql по совпадению в тексте

Tags: sql, база-данных, запрос

Здравствуйте. Имеются две таблицы:

```
1. Отдел и его менеджер

    +--------+--------+
    | name   | manager|
    +--------+--------+
    | otdel1 | ivanov |
    | otdel2 | sidorov|
    +---- ---+--------+

2. Сотрудники:

    +----------+----------------------+-------------+
    | user_name| otdel                | address     |
    +----------+----------------------+-------------+
    |   ivan   | otdel1 otdel2 otdel3 | 192.168.0.1 |
    |  masha   | otdel2               | 192.168.1.1 |
    |  sergei  | otdel1 otdel3        | 192.168.3.1 |
    +----------+----------------------+-------------+
```

Некоторые сотрудниками "числятся" в нескольких отделах.
Вопрос: как сделать выборку одним запросом всех сотрудников, имеющих отношение к какому-то конкретному менеджеру? То есть если указан менеджер ivanov, то получить ivan(192.168.0.1) и sergei(192.168.3.1)
В таблице с сотрудниками колонка otdel заполнена строковыми названиями из первой таблицы через переход строки, тип поля - TEXT

Comment: Свяжите таблицы через `join on like`

Comment: Не получится через простой like, как только появится otdel11, сразу возникнет проблема. Нужна нормальная нормализованная структура таблиц, а не каша из примера

Comment: _как только появится otdel11, сразу возникнет проблема_ `WHERE CONCAT(' ',field,' ') LIKE CONCAT('% ',literal,' %')`

Comment: Я прошу прощения за некорректный пример. По факту там не otdel1, otdel2 и тд, там "Отдел снабжения", "Отдел договорной работы" и тд. Повторений не будет.
С БД я не дружу совсем, хотелось бы пример запроса увидеть.

Answer (score 1):

ОК, если

> Повторений не будет

```
SELECT c.user_name, c.address
FROM [Сотрудники] c
  JOIN [Отдел и его менеджер] o ON с.otdel LIKE '%' + o.name + '%'
WHERE o.manager = 'ivanov'
```

Но я настаиваю на том, что нужно привести структуру таблиц в нормализованный вид. С текущей структурой вы поимеете массу проблем.

1. Такой JOIN никогда не будет использовать индекс.
2. Изменение названия, открытие, закрытие нового отдела, перевод сотрудника в другой отдел будет непростой задачей.

Добавьте в таблицы целочисленное поле id, которое будет первичным ключом, отделите сущность "Сотрудники" от принадлежности к сущности "Отдел", добавив таблицу

```
   [Сотрудники в отделах]
    (
      ID INT,
      OTDEL_ID INT,
      USER_ID  INT,
      IS_ACTIVE BIT
    )
```

Это самый минимум того, что нужно изменить.